# Why is my data not populating in Angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to grab data from my server to populate Angular Material data table but nothing is showing. I'm not sure if my dataSource is incorrect or if I did something totally wrong.

I followed the example in the docs to make sure I am doing it correctly and so far so good. Next I attempted to grab data from api and was able to achieve that task. Now I'm trying to grab data from my local server and nothing is showing. What am I missing/doing wrong

```
export interface Task {
    title: string;
    note:string;
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Task } from './task.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  private serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8000/tasks"
  // private serviceUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  getTasks():Observable<Task[]> {
    return this._http.get<Task[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './../../http.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort, MatSortable, MatTable } from '@angular/material';
import { Task } from './../../task.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'trial',
  templateUrl: './trial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trial.component.scss']
})
export class TrialComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Task>();
  displayedColumns = ['title', 'note'];

  constructor(private _httpService:HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTask();
  }

  getTask(){
    this._httpService.getTasks().subscribe(data => {
      if(!data){
        return;
      }
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)
      console.log(this.dataSource)
    })
  }
}
```

I also tried this method. Maybe someone can let me know which one is the correct or better way

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './../../http.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort, MatSortable, MatTable } from '@angular/material';
import { Task } from './../../task.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'trial',
  templateUrl: './trial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trial.component.scss']
})
export class TrialComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['title', 'note'];
  dataSource = new TasksDataSource(this._httpService);

  constructor(private _httpService:HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

export class TasksDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
  constructor(private _httpService:HttpService) {
    super();
  }

  connect():Observable<Task[]> {
    return this._httpService.getTasks();
  }

  disconnect(){}
}
```

HTML

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8"> 

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title"> 
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th> 
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task"> {{task.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="note"> 
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Note </th> 
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task"> {{task.note}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
```

my console is showing no errors. Hopefully someone can help because I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and it'g getting frustrating, and you guys know how that feels

Comment: Do you got any error from the logs ?

Comment: Try moving this line `dataSource = new TasksDataSource(this._httpService);` into the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @Nenroz Nope. No errors.

Comment: @dallows Tried it and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate a datasourc object. Just pass your Task[] to mat-table.

A better approach is to use `async` pipe to avoid to subscribe observable

```
@Component({
  selector: 'trial',
  templateUrl: './trial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trial.component.scss']
})
export class TrialComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource$: Observable<Task[]>;
  displayedColumns = ['title', 'note'];

  constructor(private _httpService:HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource$ = this.getTask();
  }

  getTask(){
    return this._httpService.getTasks().pipe(
        map((res) => res.tasks)
    );

  }
}
```

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$ | async" class="mat-elevation-z8"> 

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title"> 
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th> 
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task"> {{task.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="note"> 
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Note </th> 
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task"> {{task.note}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: I tried your code and got an error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

Comment: Ok I forgot to add a return on getTask function. Can you retry with it ?

Comment: I copied and paste your code just to double check and same error :-/

Comment: But are you sure that your server is responding something ?

Comment: You can check with a `.pipe(tap(x => console.log(x))` when calling your http service

Comment: So you need to map the http response to get tasks list. See edited answer

Comment: Awesome! Finally . Thx @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.dataSource.data = data;
```

Comment: But now I am able to see my data in the console so that's a step forward. Thx.